# How can I connect two computers with ssh but without local network

Tags: linux, ssh

I have been trying to remotely access another computer (which is outside my local network) with ssh and have not succeeded. I've done everything I've seen nothing to suggest and as I opened port 22 on both computers, I have ssh configured so as to allow access from any computer (with password) and tried to log in using the external IP (the encounter with these online pages of "what is my ip"), I have a firewall turned off, the pc from which I agree is Fedora 14 that I want to access MacOS 10.5.8.

I need this because I'm running a very heavy program at the university that I can not run on my personal laptop, but do not want to have to go every day to college for this.

I expect a solution in the best case, or any suggestions that may be relevant.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should be in serverfault. Voting to close and move

Comment: What have you done so far? The computers at my Uni have SSH enabled and I didn't have any problems yet.

Comment: Have you checked whether your university allows connections like this?  They may have a firewall set up at the network level that is preventing you from connecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:  Talk to your college IT department to setup what you need.

Knowing the external IP of a computer as seen from the "what is my ip" isn't enough to get you access to a computer behind that IP.  That IP is connected to a router (either directly, or to one upstream).  To do what you want that router needs to have firewall rules that allow access to that IP on port 22.  If the IP is directly attached to a router, then you'll need to also have forwarding enabled to get the packets to your computer (in this scenario, use the command `ifconfig` to see the IP on your computer).